# Bash script and Database

Tags: rhel, iptables, mysql, syslog

I have an iptables firewall in Linux bridge (RHEL5). I want to extract information like IP address, port number, port type, date and time, etc. from log messages using a Bash script, and then want to upload it to a MySQL database to generate the reports.

How can I do this? Is there any way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I suspect you'll get a better response from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using syslog-ng, there is a great guide [here](http://vermeer.org/docs/1). He sets up a queue: syslog-ng writes to it, and he has a consumer that reads from it and performs an SQL insert.

If you are using rsyslogd, it has [native support for mysql](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_mysql.html), but I'd still recommend the message-passing method of the first article; especially if you have high traffic spikes since the database insert takes a substantial amount of time (comparatively).